# jQuery next() with selector is not finding specified element based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure that looks like:

```
<a id="checkAllButton" onclick="...">...
<a id="uncheckAllButton" onclick="...">...
<span ...>
<div class="box collapsible-box csvTable-box">...
```

And I have a jQuery reference to the `<a>` as a result of the `onClick` of the `checkAllButton`:

When I examine (as a watch variable):

```
$(this).next().next().next()
```

I see:

```
0: div.box.collapsible-box.csvTable-box
```

However, when I use:

```
$(this).next('.csvTable-box')
```

It comes back with an empty object. It seems it should be pulling in that `<div>`, but I can't seem to determine why it's skipping over it.

[image: Chrome Watch Expressions]

Comment: The `.next()` function returns either the very next sibling, or nothing; it does not walk down the list of siblings. Consider using `.nextAll()` or `.nextUntil()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the [`.next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only returns the next adjacent element. If the very next sibling element doesn't have class `.csvTable-box`, nothing is selected.

If you want to iterate through *all* the next sibling elements, use the [`.nextAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/), and then chain [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) if you want to reduce the set so that only the first match is returned.

```
$(this).nextAll('.csvTable-box').first();
```

Comment: `.nextAll(sel).first()` if  you only want the next match